# Add Character To Each Line Except Last Using Batch File

Tags: batch-file

In this case, I was able to remove the last character but in each of line using the `~0,-1!`

As an example I want to diplay all the text from `sample.txt` from

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
Hello World4
```

to

```
Hello World1,
Hello World2,
Hello World3,
Hello World4
```

To display this txt using my created batch file `sample.bat` I'm using `EnableDelayedExpansion` with `For` loop

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type sample.txt') do (
     set disp=%%i,
     set disp=!disp:~0,-1!
     echo !disp!
)
endlocal
```

However, the output still the same as `sample.txt`

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
Hello World4
```

Comment: Your echo only displays and doesn't write to a file. Also to have the last line to have no trailing comma you have to store the current line and write the previous - so you can write the last one after the loop without the comma.

Comment: Should your Question Title not be "Add Character To Each Line Except Last Using Batch File"?

Comment: It might be me... But aren't you adding the comma and removing it immediately in the next line before echoing?

Comment: @Compo thanks for the correction. that's exactly what I meant.I already changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are adding the comma and immediately removing it before echoing. This leads to absolutely no change whatsoever as you experienced.

By commenting out that line we get closer to the desired output in your question:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type sample.txt') do (
     set disp=%%i,
REM  set disp=!disp:~0,-1!
     echo !disp!
)
endlocal
```

leads to:

> Hello World1,
>   Hello World2,
>   Hello World3,
>   Hello World4,

which still is a comma too much (if that does not matter, you are set already with the commented line.

To get the last comma away I accepted that I get an empty line instead at the top of the output. As there is no short way of getting the amount of lines in a textfile except for counting in a loop before and the counting again to skip the setting of the comma in the output I decided to not `echo` after but *before* every line. This will print the content of the variable in case there is another line in the file and else I have the modified (`%%i,`) content in the variable for even more modifications:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set disp=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type 01234.txt') do (
     echo( !disp!
     set disp=%%i,
)
set disp=!disp:~0,-1!
echo !disp!
endlocal
```

It is important to have any character immediately after the `echo` (`(` and `.` definitely work in this case). Like this there will no output if the content of the variable is empty. As you can see there is a final modification after the loop removing the comma of the last line before printing.

Comment: it's perfectly working but, I just removed the `(` after the echo for my case and the expected outcome finally worked thanks pal!. Thumbs up